# How to fix 'symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64' error in c++ boost http example

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I wanted to do a http server with boost http server sample c++11 version.
I built the project with CLion build button, it reported compile error:

```
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake --build /Users/chenyimin/CLionProjects/test_server/cmake-build-debug --target test_server -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable test_server
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "http::server::server::run()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "http::server::server::server(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My environment:

- CLion Mac 2018.2
- cmake 3.12.4
- c compiler: gcc-8
- c++ compiler: g++-8
- GDB 8.0.1
- use boost 1.68.0 lib.

My boost 1.68.0 was installed with:
brew install boost --cc=gcc-8

My boost lib's installed compiler gcc-8 should be same with the CLion build compiler gcc-8.

But it reported this error: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

main() code:

```
//
// main.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2018 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "server.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 4)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: http_server <address> <port> <doc_root>\n";
      std::cerr << "  For IPv4, try:\n";
      std::cerr << "    receiver 0.0.0.0 80 .\n";
      std::cerr << "  For IPv6, try:\n";
      std::cerr << "    receiver 0::0 80 .\n";
      return 1;
    }

    // Initialise the server.
    http::server::server s(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);

    // Run the server until stopped.
    s.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(test_server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


SET (BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/")

SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/include")

SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/lib")


set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)

find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options system thread filesystem REQUIRED )


if(Boost_FOUND)


  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})


  add_executable(test_server main.cpp)


  target_link_libraries(test_server ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

endif()
```

How to solve this problem？Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have the required packages in the following line of the CMakeLists.txt.

```
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options system thread filesystem serialization REQUIRED )
```

I was using serialization component of boost, by just adding that package it compiled all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I known why.
I changed the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test_server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

SET (BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/")
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/include")
SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0/lib")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options system thread filesystem REQUIRED )

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(test_server main.cpp server.cpp
            connection.cpp connection_manager.cpp
            request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp
            reply.cpp request.hpp mime_types.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(test_server ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

It built ok.

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer